# Run Mate without using a different operating system

Tags: mate

Is it possible to use [MATE Desktop](http://mate-desktop.org/) on top of standard LTS Ubuntu?

I would like to try MATE. But I would like to stick with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But for first experience I can recommend to install it on virtual machine or test with LiveCD/LiveUSB.

On already installed Ubuntu LTS you should install Ubuntu MATE meta-package with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

and then select MATE session on the login screen.

---

Removing GNOME session is also possible with:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop \
ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-unity-desktop unity-session
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

And main GNOME software may be removed with (**do not run it if unsure**):

```
sudo apt-get purge activity-log-manager aisleriot alacarte baobab eog \
evince evince-common evolution-data-server-common file-roller gedit \
gedit-common gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 \
gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-calendar \
gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-font-viewer \
gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-mahjongg gnome-menus gnome-mines \
gnome-online-accounts gnome-panel gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver \
gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common \
gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-appindicator \
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-software gnome-software-common \
gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal \
gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data \
gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-user-docs gnome-user-guide \
libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-games-support-1-3 \
libgnome-games-support-common libgnomekbd8 libgnomekbd-common \
libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-todo metacity mutter-common \
nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-extension-brasero \
nautilus-sendto network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu rhythmbox \
software-center totem totem-common webbrowser-app xwayland zeitgeist-core

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After executing of these two commands you will get the system very similar to standard [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) 18.04 LTS installation.