# 18.04 Mate top panel double trouble

Tags: 18.04, indicator, ubuntu-mate

Ok, been using Gnome in 18.04, but I wanted some of that good old Unity again. So, I installed Mate-desktop. It works ok until it does not work.
Sometimes when I log in, and especially after I log out and log back in I get double everything - two indicators, two menus, and two brisk-menus and two trash bins.
[image]
It is a terrible experience. How can this be prevented? I very much would like to use Mate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider to reset panel settings with

1. To be completely sure reset permissions on all dot-folders with

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.[a-zA-Z]*
   ```
2. Open MATE Terminal and reset MATE Panel settings with `dconf` by

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/mate/panel/
   ```
3. Open MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`) again and select *Mutiny* layout.
4. Relaunch MATE Panel with

   ```
   killall mate-panel 
   mate-panel --replace &
   ```

   or logout and login again.

---

Notes:
1. I tested this method on clean installation of Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS.
2. You can remove GNOME-related stuff as mentioned in [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097974/66509) but it **is dangerous**.

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Try to repeat listed actions until success.