# Removing Gnome shell from Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Long story short: I installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on my home server (because Ubuntu server kept failing on install.) I configured Grub to load directly to command line. I would really like to uninstall GUI interface--make it lean and have less programs to update.

If I uninstalled gnome, will that affect any other functionality? What's the best way to uninstall Gnome to avoid any unintended consequences?

(I've reviewed a few other posts, but most seem to be about using Unity after uninstalling Gnome.)

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu server kept failing on install?"

Comment: See my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097974/66509) - you may consider to have MATE instead of GNOME.

Comment: @user535733 I believe I was only able to install the desktop version when I checked the 'install third party software' option.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but for anyone else reading this, OP seems to be confusing between a "Desktop Minimal Install" and an install from a minimal image. If you are trying to setup a server, you need to download a minimal ISO and start the installation from there instead of using a desktop ISO and trying to use the minimal option during desktop install, they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem with starting from a Desktop install** is that *hundreds* of desktop packages were apt-marked **specifically** to prevent users from accidentally removing their GUI. Removing the top-level Gnome packages WON'T autoremove hundreds of libs underneath, and definitely won't accomplish what you want without a lot of tedious effort.

Users who wish to convert should either:

1) Use the [Server installer](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), [Minimal Image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), or [Cloud Image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) (not for bare metal), or

2) Embrace the package overhead.

Since you said that #1 doesn't work for you, then seems like #2 is your preferred alternative. If #2 bugs you, then revisit your assumptions about #1.

Comment: So I tried the minimal installation, but it wouldn't finish installation unless I selected the "install third-party software" option.

Comment: Then you were not using the Minimal installer. The third-party option is part of the Desktop installer. Big difference.

Comment: This was the way. Although I had to install desktop version to get Grub and partition the drives. Then I erased the partitions and installed the Ubuntu server. Which has been just what I wanted. No GUI programs to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

Remove xorg, wayland and related packages. This will effectively take down any graphical application as these all depend on the xserver. Do an autoremove after this (`sudo apt autoremove`). Then install the metapackage `ubuntu-server`. This will install any package that is considered a part of the ubuntu server installation as seen by the Canonical developpers. If removing xserver ever removed packages you need for a server (which I am pretty convinced it won't), this command will pull them back in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I remove gnome-shell as well? Also,I was able to remove xorg but not wayland.

Comment: I assume you are working from a recovery terminal before trying to remove the graphical stack? You can't just remove a chair while you are sitting on it. Removing both wayland and xorg will automaticallyremove all packages that depend on them.